# Different results when running from Eclipse and different from executable jar file

Tags: jar, executable

My application works good when running from Eclipse, but results from executable jar files are wrong. Am I making some mistakes during export?

Thanks

Comment: I swear I thought the problem in my pc ! yes I have the same problem so if you had, so help me if you found a solution